# Handling alignment for the base64 image while converting html to pdf in django

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

This is a sample code that is calling the function to create chart and convert it into bytecode. 
The first function is to convert image to bytecode,
The second function creates piechart using matplotlib package and third creates barchart using same package

```py
def convert_image_to_bytes(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as imageFile:
        byte_img = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
        return 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+byte_img.decode('utf-8')

def create_piechart(recovered, totalissue, total_failed):
    labels = 'Failed Validations', 'Boot up issues', 'VMs Ok'
    sizes = [total_failed, totalissue, recovered]
    print(sizes)
    colors = ['Green', 'Orange', 'Red']
    print(colors)
    # Plot
    plt.pie(sizes, labels=labels, colors=colors,
            autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('templates/piechart.jpg', bbox_inches="tight")
    image_bytes = convert_image_to_bytes('templates/piechart.jpg')
    return image_bytes


def create_barchart(os):
    objects = ('Unknown', 'Linux', 'Solaris', 'Windows')
    objects = tuple(os.keys())
    print(objects)
    y_pos = arange(len(objects))
    performance = list(server_os.values())
    print(performance)
    plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5, color = 'orange')
    plt.yticks(y_pos, objects)
    plt.ylabel('Number of VMs of each flavor')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('templates/barchart.jpg', bbox_inches="tight")
    image_bytes = convert_image_to_bytes('templates/barchart.jpg')
    return image_bytes

'''
"This is a sample code that takes input fromt the function where i call it and then create the chart and again convert it into bytes."
```

Comment: Can you please share some code, so we can replicate the problem and help you?

Comment: the whole can be achieved by using `pdfkit` and once the file is  created open it and read as `rb` which will be the same. + it will be without errors